# What am I doing wrong in solving this easy competitive programming question? (Project Euler - Problem 5)

Tags: java

This is my first question on StackOverflow so please pardon any mistakes but let me know about them. I am trying to do problem 5 on Project Euler in Java. I feel like my code is correct but I can not get the answer.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a = true;
        int counter = 0;
        int b = 1;

        while (a) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) { 
                if (b % i == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter == 20) {
                    System.out.println(b);
                    a = false;
                }
                else {
                    b++;
                }

                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add what project Euler's 5th java question is to your post.

Comment: Wait, what? Where do arrays get involved here?

Comment: What is your question? What do you not understand about your code exactly?

Comment: @Jens I did not use arrays in my code and a number can't divided by zero, so for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your nesting is wrong.

Within the `for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)` loop you increment `counter` if `b` is divisible by `i`.

The you do some checks and in the end set `counter` to zero again.

That means that your `counter` only ever reaches a maximum value of 1 (if `b` is divisible by a specific `i`).

You probably meant to write

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) { 
            if (b % i == 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 20) {
            System.out.println(b);
            a = false;
        }
        else {
            b++;
        }

        counter = 0;
```

which will give the correct result - although the algorithm is still terribly slow.